# Pros and cons of integrating hadoop with OBIEE

Tags: hadoop, obiee

I am studying about integrating hadoop with OBIEE. However I am unable to find any good article highlighting pros and cons of integrating Hadoop with OBIEE.if anyone has this information kindly share the link/details.

Answer (score 0):

- Pros: You can get your data from Hadoop
- Cons: Pointless, unless your data is in Hadoop

As a question this really doesn't make much sense. You integrate OBIEE with wherever your data is, in order to analyse it.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Robin. The point if a source-agnostic tool is to analyze data wherever it lies.

Pushing data to a new storage "just because" isn't adding value. You have to have a reason like performance, explicit physical modelling (multidimensional cubes for example) or the likes.